# Where to get market capitalization data for these two indexes?

Tags: index, market

I am looking for historical market capitalization for:

- SPX 500 index
- MSCI EAFE index

Bloomberg data for market capitalization oddly enough only seems to start in 2000s.
Which other paid or free databases can I try?

Edit: I am voting to reopen this. The duplicate question is a repository of databases and does not answer this question directly.

Comment: I am not sure voting to re-open your own post is an exemplary approach. In addition, I think it is best if one goes and check herself/himself if the sources listed in the answers to the duplicate has what s/he is looking for in addition to the other obvious vendors such as S&P or MSCI themselves. It is not realistic to expect all data series available from each source to be listed in the answers to the duplicate. Yardeni Research, for example, is one of the sources listed in the answers to the duplicate and it seems to carry old mcap data for S&P 500 for its subscribers.

Comment: That is not a complete answer to the question above and "seems to carry" is also not an answer. Your answer is akin to asking a question and being told to: "check all the books in the library". Also I edited my question and justified why I voted to reopen it.